# 13.04 doesn't seem to install grub correctly. 12.04 works perfectly

Tags: grub2, 13.04

I've tried several attempts at installing 13.04 on a machine. ONCE, it worked correctly, but I've never been able to get it to work again. I've tried kubuntu, stock ubuntu, and even mint. They all seem to act the same way.

After it installs and tells me to remove the media and hit enter, it gets to the bios screen and the bios says to insert media. I've confirmed that it's attempting to boot from the correct drive (the one I told the install to use).

If I can be of any help, please let me know. I'm very keen on using kubuntu-desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to customize my partition layout using the MBR layout (ie, no special partitions for UEFI boot information/grub).

That doesn't work.

I installed without specifying a partition layout (just let it have it's way with the disk) and now everything seems to work fine. In fact, my UEFI says "ubuntu" as a boot option now.

Thanks for trying to save me from myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-install grub wit boot-repair there is a tutorial [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: I found that after I asked the question. When I get back to the computer I will reinstall 13.04 and give that a shot. I really want to use 13.04 because of the great multi-monitor support, but I wonder if 12.04 (after updated) has the same application to edit the orientation and physical arrangement of monitors.

Comment: I've even updated my bios. 13.04 won't boot after install. That .iso will not boot at all, it gives garbage output when I try to boot it.

Comment: @user167208 have you tried to install boot-repair on the live dvd/usb you installed Ubuntu  with in the first place, described as the second option at the page I linked?

Comment: I just reinstalled ubuntu 13.04-desktop x64. When it goes to shutdown after install finishes, it hangs with the screen black. I waited a long time (several minutes) and hit enter, and it reboot. Now it is stuck on "GRUB " with a cursor flashing. I'm going to try boot repair from the live CD. I tried it from ISO and it failed to boot.

Comment: did you test if your cd is correct. you could consider re-downloading the iso, [check de md5 sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) and burn it (or make a live usb, my preferred method because it is reusable)